# Stochastic integral with respect to fractional Brownian motion.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

How is the stochastic integral
$$\int_0^t S(t)dB_H(t)$$

defined ,where $B_H$ is a fractional brownian motion and $H \neq 1/2$.As far as I understand the fractional brownian motion is not a semimartingale so the usual definition of stochastic integral is not valid here.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, one has to find new methods to postulate a consistent calculus for fractional Brownian motion.

Some approaches are

- rough paths [A CONSTRUCTION OF THE ROUGH PATH ABOVE FRACTIONAL BROWNIAN MOTION USING VOLTERRA’S REPRESENTATION](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.1307.pdf)
- Malliavin calculus ["Stochastic calculus with respect to fractional Brownian motion with Hurst parameter lesser than 1/2"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414999000897) and ["Stochastic calculus with respect to fractional Brownian"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414999000897)
- a pathwise approach eg. ["Integration with respect to fractal functions and stochastic calculus. I"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s004400050171)